# Button press & release actions (php)

Tags: php

I want to create a button with press & release actions, so, for example, when i press it, it shows some text and when i release it it hides the text. Can anybody help?
What i have already tried:

```
    <form action="forwardon.php" method="get">
     <input type="submit" value="Forward">
    </form>
```

This just creates a button which redirects to a page which is running the desired action: but you cant create press & release actions with this..

And i cant find any way how to do this.. Or is it just not possible with php?

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this? Seems like a JavaScript issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes. It's not possible with php, you need to use javascript for that.

Every button has events: `onmousedown` and `onmouseup`. You can see the list of events [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

Basically, you need to create functions, that will be fired in javascript while pressing/releasing. It would look like this

```
<html>
<-- your html here -->
</html>
<script>
    document.getElementById('id-of-your-button')
        .addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
            //change the text you need here with pure javascript
        });
</script>
```

The same goes with `onmouseup` event too.

To know more about javascript visit [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to run a php script from javascript? I want to use exec, but that only works from php.. Or is there a javascript alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Like James already said. In PHP it isn't possible to make something like button events, because PHP is a ServerSideLanguage.

As he also mentioned, you have to use for example JavaScript.

**With the following script you are able to change the text with mouse events**

```
<input type="button" value="Forward" onmousedown="getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'pressed';" onmouseup="getElementById('text').innerHTML = '';">
<p id="text"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

PHP won't be able to do this without refreshing the page/going to a new page.

JavaScript can give you what you are looking for.

see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) first example for showing text.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is really a comment, and not an actual answer to the question

Comment: I can't comment I would have if I could - you need > 50 reputation to comment